# Unsecured Content Warnings on Pages With SSL for external links ?

Tags: ssl, https

I have a page with an SSL certificate. 
I already know that if I call assets (images and javascript) through HTTP I will receive an Unsecure Content Warning, but my question is: What happend If I have external links (`<a />`) (for example to a PDF file) through HTTP? 
Will I receive an Unsecure Content Warning or not ?

e.g.

```
<a href='http://external.path.to/something.pdf'>External Link</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because mixed content is about the current page.

Insecure images, scripts, css or iframes impact the current page.

Links to insecure content do not trigger warnings but if you submit a form from a secure page to an insecure one it may trigger a warning.

Comment: @mondi please explain.